# Amazon EC2 prompt password when sudo

Tags: amazon-ec2

When I log into an ec2 instance via ssh using keypair (logged in as ec2-user user), I am able to execute `sudo` commands without typing a password.

How can I configure ec2 instance to prompt for a password when the logged in user issues a `sudo` command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Warning: Make sure to set the password for ec2-user before doing this**

You need to modify the sudo settings to enable password authentication when using sudo. Run the `visudo` command as root (or `sudo visudo`) and look for a line like this:

```
ec2-user        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Remove the `NOPASSWD:` bit, so the line looks like this:

```
ec2-user        ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

`sudo` will ask for a password next time you log on. Again, make sure to set your password before doing this!

Comment: I think that next time you should put 'Make sure to set your password before doing this!' at the very top and in bold.

Comment: What should I do if I didn't set a password? :)

Comment: Redeploy the instance using your automated deployment process ;) It's a bit of a workaround, but you can connect the disk of your current container to a different instance as a second disk, mount it and change the `/etc/sudoers` file. Then unmount and reconnect it to the original instance and boot it.

Comment: yeah this doesn't work.

Comment: A good tip while you're changing the sudoer's file, is that you have 2 terminals to the system open.
    1) Open one terminal to the system on the console as a plain user
    2) Open a second terminal to the system in "sudo vim /etc/sudoers" (or whatever your editor)
    3) Make the changes. Hit save. Do not quit the editor!
    4) Use the first terminal you had open to test those changes: sudo echo foobar
    5) If something went wrong, open up that editor window you still have open and make corrections.

Comment: I'm not sure when this change occurred, but on my EC2 running Amazon Linux 2, the `ec2-user` entry was in `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users`